# django-compressor CommandError: An error occurred during rendering file/path.html: Invalid class path 'css'

Tags: django, django-compressor

I'm trying to use `django-compressor` for my project. So far in my development environment, when I run `python manage.py compress` I been get this error `CommandError: An error occurred during rendering D:path/to/a/template.html: Invalid class path 'css'`

I have lots of template files spread across many apps. The error pops up randomly, pointing to a different template each time I run `python manage.py compress`.

I have also tried first running `python manage.py collectstatic`, but to no avail and nothing in the [docs](https://django-compressor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) seem to mention this error

`OS: Windows 10`, `Django==2.0.5`, `django-compressor==2.2`

Relevant `settings.py` section below

```
DEBUG = True
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

COMPRESS_ROOT = STATIC_ROOT
COMPRESS_URL = STATIC_URL
COMPRESS_PARSER = 'compressor.parser.HtmlParser'
COMPRESS_ENABLED = True
COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True
COMPRESS_OFFLINE_MANIFEST = 'compressor_manifest.json'
COMPRESS_CSS_FILTERS = {
    'css': ['compressor.filters.css_default.CssAbsoluteFilter'], 
    'js': ['compressor.filters.jsmin.JSMinFilter']
}
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/x-scss', 'django_libsass.SassCompiler'),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)
```

Inside the `<head></head>` tag of my project's `base.html` template I have

```
{% load compress %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static %}

{% compress css file %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/fname.css' %}">
{% endcompress %}

{% compress js file %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/fname.js' %}"></script>
{% endcompress %}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must define [`COMPRESS_FILTERS`](https://django-compressor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings/#backend-settings) instead of `COMPRESS_CSS_FILTERS` as the latter is only a backwards-compatible alias for the `css` key of the former. That is, your configuration should read:

```
COMPRESS_FILTERS = {
    'css': ['compressor.filters.css_default.CssAbsoluteFilter'], 
    'js': ['compressor.filters.jsmin.JSMinFilter']
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I must admit I never really looked at that properly. I had some filters defined the old style. Now I come upon the new style in the docs and I totally did not update the variable name. Too bad and thanks